# Scala pattern matching against URLs

Tags: scala

Is there a Scala library/example that will parse a URL/URI into a case class structure for pattern matching?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's an extractor that will get some parts out of a URL for you:

```
object UrlyBurd {
  def unapply(in: java.net.URL) = Some((
    in.getProtocol, 
    in.getHost, 
    in.getPort,
    in.getPath
  ))
}

val u = new java.net.URL("http://www.google.com/")

u match {
  case UrlyBurd(protocol, host, port, path) => 
    protocol + 
      "://" + host + 
      (if (port == -1) "" else ":" + port) + 
      path
}
```

Comment: For bonus points, one could have a sequence extraction for the path. :-)

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to use the facility provided by [extractors for regular expressions](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html#24.7).

For instance:

```
val URL = """(http|ftp)://(.*)\.([a-z]+)""".r

def splitURL(url : String) = url match {
  case URL(protocol, domain, tld) => println((protocol, domain, tld))
}

splitURL("http://www.google.com") // prints (http,www.google,com)
```

Some explanations:

- The `.r` method on strings (actually, on `StringLike`s) turns them into an instance of `Regex`.
- `Regex`es define an `unapplySeq` method, which allows them to be used as [extractors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) in pattern-matching (note that you have to give them a name that starts with a capital letter for this to work).
- The values that are going to be passed into the binders you use in the pattern are defined by the groups `(...)` in the regular expression.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the regex returns Seq[String]? If I need to do more complex matching against query string parameters, I would probably parse those as well and do something like: case class Url(protocol: String, domain: String, tld: String, uri: String, Tuple2[String, String] queryStringParameters))

Comment: @Eric the method above will return whatever is after the `=>`. As defined, it returns `Unit`, but you could change the `println...` to `(protocol, domain, tld)` for a tuple, `Seq(protocol, domain, tld)` if you want a Seq, or your case class if you define one.

Comment: Using a regex to parse URLs is well into WORLD OF PAIN territory, but extractors are a good technique...

Comment: As the saying goes - `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.`

Comment: Point taken :) I would argue though that URLs are just before the final frontier of the unregexable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [java's URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) which can parse an URL for its different components and is completely Scala compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The following library can help you parse URIs into an instance of a case class. (Disclaimer: it is my own library)
https://github.com/theon/scala-uri

You parse like so:

```
import com.github.theon.uri.Uri._
val uri:Uri = "http://example.com?one=1&two=2"
```

It provides a DSL for building URLs with query strings:

```
val uri = "http://example.com" ? ("one" -> 1) & ("two" -> 2)
```

Comment: is there a way to check if URLs are valid without having to catch exceptions? E.g. when I try to do `val uri: Uri = "$%&"`, then I get a strange `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`