# How to detect urls in scala

Tags: scala

Hello for example there is file with content and url's. I want only the content of urls is there any detector in scala.Kindly suggest me any idea.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For this and many other questions: you could just use solution for `Java`.

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285880/406435)

```
import java.net.URL; import util.Try

val text = "abc http://stackoverflow.com stackoverflow.com http blah-blah-blah"

text.split{"""\s+"""}.map{ s => Try { new URL(s) } }.flatMap{ _.toOption }
//Array[java.net.URL] = Array(http://stackoverflow.com)
```

Comment: You might want to consider using java.net.URI, rather than java.net.URL. URL has some pathological behaviour. For example, methods like hashCode and equals make outgoing network connections.

Answer (score 0):

About this topic read [Extract URL from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string) . It doesn't matter in which programming language you want to use, the problem is always the same. I faced to the same challenge in 2011 and I went the way that was posted in the accepted answer (as far as I can remember with a little modification).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I understood you correctly, but you can try writing your own. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586605/scala-pattern-matching-against-urls) post. After creating a correct regular expression you may do sth like this (the code assumes that urls are in different lines than the rest of the content):

```
val URL = """(http|ftp)://(.*)\.([/a-z]+)""".r
def splitURL(url: String) = url match {
  case URL(protocol, domain, tld) => println((protocol, domain, tld))
  case _ => ; // skip
}

val f = new File("file.txt")
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines()

lines foreach (splitURL)
```

This is just a hint. You will probably need sth more customized for your particular case.

**Edit:**

You probably need more advanced regular expression. Have a look at reporter's answer